# URL Routing to Child View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have setup a parent view with multiple child views, and it seems to be working with no problem in the application.  The problem is if you refresh the page or try to go directly to the child view with the appropriate url.

Here are my states that I am loading.  This the parent state:

```
{name: "myTeam", url: "/myTeam", template: "<my-team></my-team>"}
```

Here's one of the children:

```
{name: "myTeam.info", url: "/info", template: "<my-team.info></my-team.info>"}
```

Here's another:

```
{name: "myTeam.checkin", url: "/checkin/{book}/{club}/{team}/{bus}", template: "<my-team.checkin></my-team.checkin>"}
```

So, if I visit the Info view, it loads the template correctly and sets the url to "/myTeam/info".  If try to refresh the page or just start out at the url "/myTeam/info", it won't load the state/template.

I added code to the angular-ui-router.js (version 0.1.2) to try to debug.  I added the console.log() line at line 912.

```
UrlMatcher.prototype.exec = function (path, searchParams) {
  var m = this.regexp.exec(path);
  console.log("  -->  " + this.regexp + " -- " + path + " = " + m);
  if (!m) return null;
  searchParams = searchParams || {};
```

Here's the output:

```
  -->  /^\/myTeam\/?$/ -- /myTeam/info = null
  -->  /^\/info(.*)?\/?$/ -- /myTeam/info = null
  -->  /^\/checkin\/([^\/]*)?\/([^\/]*)?\/([^\/]*)?\/([^\/]*)?(.*)?\/?$/ -- /myTeam/info = null
```

So, it's not matching on the parent or the child.

I was following the example on the [Nested States and Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-and-nested-views).  Their urls looked the same to me.

I don't see how it makes a difference, but I am using the [UI extras](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future) to load these as future states and using the [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad).

Any thoughts on how I can get the URL to work?  Or, how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

I finally determined that the problem was with the UI Extras and future state loading.

I ended out taking the easy road for time's sake.  I changed my project to not use any child states, and that takes care of my problem.

From the best I can tell, it is not loading all of the children states.  The future state loader is only matching the parent and loading the parent.

I think my problem is similar to this problem that I found here:
[UI Router Extras Issue #63](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/63)

I attempted to write code in my future state loader that would load the parent state and all of it's children.  That forced me to have to modify the UI Router Extras to accept an array of promises, and I had to modify too many things to make it work.

Hopefully, at some point I can try to build a more complete fix outside my project and contribute it, but for now, my solution is to avoid child states.

Answer (score 0):

weird, my project have children states, and some children have more children states too, and it's working fine without problems, i will show you how i setup my url:

***dashboardState.js***

the state with `url: ''` is the home page, and it is loaded when you navigate to url /home, but their children home loads inside dashboard.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .config(dashboardStates);

    function dashboardStates($stateProvider) {

        var dashboard = {
            name: 'dashboard',
            abstract: true,
            url: '/home', // view inicial abaixo
            templateUrl: 'app/components/Dashboard/view/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController',
            controllerAs: 'dashboard'
        };

        var dashboardHome = {
            name: 'dashboard.home',
            url: '',
            parent: 'dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/Dashboard/view/dashboard.home.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController',
            controllerAs: 'home',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                label: 'Home'
            }
        };


        // states
        $stateProvider
            .state(dashboard)
            .state(dashboardHome);
    }

}());
```

and the state below loads inside the **dashboard** view:

***profileState.js***

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .config(profileStates);

    function profileStates($stateProvider) {

        var profile = {
            name: 'dashboard.profile',
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/Profile/view/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
            controllerAs: 'profile'
        };

        var profileEdit = {
            name: 'dashboard.profile.edit',
            url: '/edit',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/Profile/view/profile.edit.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
            controllerAs: 'profile'
        };

        $stateProvider
            .state(profile)
            .state(profileEdit);
    }

}());
```

more info: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

Comment: Are any of your states lazy loaded?  I've come to believe that that is my problem.  When I took out my lazy loading, it worked fine.

I am lazy loading the states so that I can load only the states that the current user has security to.  An $http request checks security and returns the list of states.